# Beacon not detected and need suggestions on how to start new Activity when beacon is detected

Tags: java, android, android-studio, beacon, eddystone

I have two days left to figure this code out, so I had to choice but to write a question here in hope that I will get some answers.
I am making an application that should detect beacons and once a beacon is detected, a specific activity should open. 
I adapted the code from https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-how-to.html 
I have an eddystone beacon but I get no information in the log.d about beacons or even if it scans for beacons. I have to mention that I tried various ways to make this work but I think the pressure of having to finish the app is starting to get to me and I can't make it work.
So the question I have is : what is wrong with my code below and how can I make an activity open once the beacon is detected? Thank you

```html
package com.example.florentina.discoverlondon;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Identifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.MonitorNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier;

import java.util.Collection;

public class Beacon_Activity extends MainActivity implements BeaconConsumer {
    public static final String TAG = "BeaconsEverywhere";
    // Beacon Manager Variable
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;

    //GUI Text Label
    TextView rangeElement;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Vars for XML Elements
        rangeElement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.range);

        // Instantiate a Beacon Manager via factory method
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

        // Tell Library how to decode the signal
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
                .setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
        // Detect the telemetry Eddystone-TLM frame:
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_TLM_LAYOUT));
        // Start the Beacon Manager
        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    // When the Beacon Service starts, search for Beacons with the following Identifier
    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        Identifier myBeaconNamespaceId = Identifier.parse("620fb7f886bece801a16");
        Identifier myBeaconInstanceId = Identifier.parse("495162a49005");
        final org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region = new org.altbeacon.beacon.Region("myBeacons", myBeaconNamespaceId, myBeaconInstanceId, null);
        beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
            // If the phone enters a Beacon region

            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "did Enter Region");
                    beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);

                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // If the phone leaves a Beacon region
            @Override
            public void didExitRegion(org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "did Exit Region");
                    beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {

            }
        });

        // If the phone finds a Beacon fitting the rules, print it in the console
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            //Log out welche beacons in der Nähe sind
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {
                for(final Beacon oneBeacon : beacons) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "distance: " + oneBeacon.getDistance() + "id: " + oneBeacon.getId1() + "/" + oneBeacon.getId2() + "/" + oneBeacon.getId3());

                    // Access UI thread and make changes to the UI
                    // Placing rangeElement.setText outside of the Runnable will crash the App
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // Change the text label in the UI
                            rangeElement.setText(String.valueOf(oneBeacon.getDistance()));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // When the App gets closed, stop the Beacon Manager
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since it doesn't sound like your code is close to working, I suggest you  simply start over with the reference app here:  https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference, which will out of the box detect AltBeacon and launch a new activity.  Get that working first.  Once that works, add the code to detect Eddystone.  Once that works, modify the program as needed.   Each time you get one of these steps to work, save what you have so you can go back to it if your subsequent changes break something.  Use the free free Beacon Locate app to transmit AltBeacon on a 2nd phone.